# Sort files by number in the end of a file name

Tags: powershell, sorting, substring, ps

I need help with a tricky task I have.

I have a list of *.xml files which have the same ending.
The names below show only the naming convention rule.

EEEEEEEEEE-JJJ-ZZZZZ_DDDDD-XML--0000001629358212.xml

EEEEEEEEEE-JJJ-OOOOOO-XML--0000001533506936.xml

EEEEEEEEEE-JJJ-AAAAAA-XML--0000001572627196.xml

Filename length maybe is different but it's important for me to sort it by this number in the end.
With SQL syntax it would be easier but I need a PS solution).

Sort-Object by LastWriteTime works better than other simple ways - but when it comes to a few files with the same hh:mm PS mixes the order.

At the beginning of the chains of steps that should happen with these files, I remove a time stamps from the beginning of each file name.
I was able to do it with this:

`dir *EEEEEEEEEE*.xml | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name.substring($_.BaseName.IndexOf("EEEEEEEEE"))}`

But I'm unable to write something similar for sorting.

Maybe someone can advise how to solve it? Maybe You have more experience with PS Substring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please remove the part that DOES NOT apply to your Question - the rename stuff has nothing to do with the Question you have asked. ///// you can sort by a calculated value. so try sorting by splitting on the hyphen and taking the last item in the  resulting array.

Answer (score 2):

Read and follow [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Sort-Object), scrolling down to the `-Property` parameter:

> …
>  The Property parameter's value can be a calculated property. To
> create a calculated property, use a hash table.
>
> Valid keys for a hash table are as follows:
>
> ```
> expression              - <string> or <script block>
> ascending or descending - <boolean>
> ```
>
> For more information, see [about_Calculated_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties).

Read the [*Examples*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Sort-Object?view=powershell-5.1#examples) section as well. Use

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter "*EEEEEEEEEE*-*.xml" |
  Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = { ($_.BaseName -split '-')[-1] }}
```

Comment: Nice, though a mere script block as the calculated property is (usually, and certainly here) is sufficient: `Sort-Object -Property { ($_.BaseName -split '-')[-1] }`. It is unfortunate that [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) help topic doesn't make this clearer (as of this writing) - [GitHub docs issue #7854](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/7854) asks to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help.

I used this line below and it worked in my case.
`GCI EEEEEEEEEE*.xml | Sort {$_.Name.substring($_.Name.Length - 20,14)}` 
It reads only the number at the end of the file name and sorts the files in the way I need.

Best regards